# Understanding of Camera API

Tags: android, camera

Although Camera API is deprecated, it's simpler to get started than Camera2. But the document seems not to be that easy to understand(with my reading ability). I've searched a lot trying to figure it out. But there're still bunch of questions.

> 1.What is camera's orientation? Is there any definition that I miss? There're 4 dimensions(left, top, right, bottom) of camera. When we say **orientation**, which one is used and what is the relative object?
>
> 2.Why it's different between camera's orientation and device's?
>
> 3.Could you please tell me how to understand the algorithm given in the document of [Camera.setDisplayOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) and [Camera.parameters.setRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int))? There're sample code given by document for these two methods. These two algorithm both use **sum** and **difference** of orientation/rotation. I may use it directly in my project. But what does that mean exactly?
>
> Besides, taking back-facing camera as example, the former uses `(info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360`, while the latter uses `(info.orientation + orientation) % 360`. Confusing:/

Thanks if you can answer any of these questions above or just share some of your thoughts and experiences.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** it is the how the camera is orientated in your device

**2.** Device orientation is the current orientation/rotation of your device (landscape/portrait )

**3.** **Camera.setDisplayOrientation()**

affects the preview

**Camera.parameters.setRotation()**

affects the result pictures (jpeg etc.)

---

**Documentation:**

**[Camera.setDisplayOrientation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int))**

> Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This affects
>   the preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot. This
>   method is useful for portrait mode applications. Note that preview
>   display of front-facing cameras is flipped horizontally before the
>   rotation, that is, the image is reflected along the central vertical
>   axis of the camera sensor. So the users can see themselves as looking
>   into a mirror.

**[Camera.parameters.setRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int))**

> Sets the clockwise rotation angle in degrees relative to the orientation of the camera. This affects the pictures returned from JPEG Camera.PictureCallback. The camera driver may set orientation in the EXIF header without rotating the picture. Or the driver may rotate the picture and the EXIF thumbnail. If the Jpeg picture is rotated, the orientation in the EXIF header will be missing or 1 (row #0 is top and column #0 is left side).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question. Hope to take a look .

Comment: I don't know what "camera's orientation on earth" mean. Never heard of the. The reference object for the Camera orientation is the phone itself in portrait orientation

Comment: But 'phone itself in portrait orientation' is phone's orientation which is not 'Camera's orientation'. Besides, I just remove 'on earth' in question.

Comment: check this out: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-camera-orientation-made-simple

Comment: The link is useful. But what confuse me is **The Fix** in that blog. It uses same code for both `Camera.setDisplayOrientation()` and `Camera.parameters.setRotation()`. While the sample code offered in `Camera.parameters.setRotation()` is not.

Comment: Seems perfectly fine to use the same function. You might also use the sample code of Camera.parameters.setRotation() (I didn't read that) and set the DisplayOrientation also.